# How to remove properties from Google Analytics, but not delete data for other users?

Tags: google-analytics, google-account

My Google Analytics account contains 4 Properties. 3 of the properties are websites I do not own. They belong to another user.

How can I remove the 3 properties from my account, without deleting the data for the other user?

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about configuring Google Analytics

Comment: okay. but do you have an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the other user to remove permissions to their account.